# Treat Spark RDD like plain Seq

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming, rdd

I have a CLI application for transforming JSONs. Most of it's code is `map`ping, `flatMap`ping and traversing with `for` Lists of JValues. Now I want to port this application to Spark, but seems I need to rewrite all functions 1:1, but write `RDD[JValue]` instead of `List[JValue]`.

Is there any way (like type class) for function to accept both Lists and RDDs.

Comment: The method signature of map on List and on RDD aren't the same, so this will be a pain. You might be able to go with a typeclass approach and define your own wrapper for their map, providing an instance for both. If you could define scalaz monad and traverse instances for RDD you might be able to use that.

Comment: I think there's shouldn't be problems with functor. But at first glance RDD doesn't hold Monad laws.

Comment: If RDD doesn't obey the monad laws then you won't be able to FlatMap with the the scalaz typeclass. That said you might be able to implement a version that doesn't obey the laws and it *might* work for your specific needs. Similar to providing ValidationFlatMap

Comment: Hm. Probably that's the way to go. I know that for example scala's Future isn't monad either, but it provides flatMap and treated like monad. Thank you, I'll try it.

Comment: If that works it would be great to post an answer with the typeclass instances for Monad and Traverse that you come up with.

Comment: Did you end up writing these typeclasses? I'm interested in how you solved this.

Comment: Hey @Daenyth. I ended up with rewritten 1:1 solution, sadly. Problem of type class approach is that this `MonadLike` start to propagate to unrelated code, so it's simpler for me leave as is. But it worked.

Comment: suhailshergill has some code related to your problem: https://gist.github.com/suhailshergill/3ca97f3637db65af3c78

Answer (score 2):

If you want to share your code for processing local & abstract code you can move your lambdas/anaonymous functions that you pass in to `map`/`flatMap` into named functions and re-use them.

If you want to re-use your logic for how to order the maps/flatMaps/etc, you could also create an implicit conversions between both `RDD` and `Seq` to a custom trait which has only the shared functions but implicit conversions can become quite confusing and I don't really think this is a good idea (but you *could* do it if you disagree with me :)).

Comment: I think that conversions actually need to involve actions, so RDD will be computed.

Comment: indeed, you would also have to have an action in your common trait for it to ever do some work. I really think the right way to do this is by factoring our the shared logic inside the map/flatMap/etc if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you. Probably it will be my choice if I couldn't find something more appropriate. The problem is that that lambda-functions now combined into bigger ones, so factoring out will uglify it a bit. I also think about use of `Either`.